# R: function choose, efficient

Tags: r, performance, apply

I need to speed up my R-code. My bottleneck is a function that needs to use the choose function. It looks like this:

```
P_ni <- function(Pn,Pi,eta1,eta2,p,d=NA)
{
 if(is.na(d)) d <- 1-p
 if(Pn==Pi) output <- p^Pn
 else
 {
  if(Pi==1)seq1 <- seq_len(Pn-1)
  if(Pi>1)seq1 <- seq_len(Pn-1)[-seq_len(Pi-1)]
  output <- sum(choose((Pn-Pi-1),c(seq1-Pi))*choose(Pn,seq1)*
    (eta1/(eta1+eta2))^c(seq1-Pi)*
    (eta2/(eta1+eta2))^c(Pn-seq1)*p^seq1*d^c(Pn-seq1)
  )
 }
 return(output)
}
```

This function need to be called several times with different Pn and Pi. The Problem here is, that Pn and Pi only are able to take a single number and not work with vectors. This is caused by the choose()-function.

I do this with a for-loop at the moment and it works perfectly, but it is slow.
The for-loop looks like this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(n_k_matrix_p)) 
{
  n_k_matrix_p[i,4] <- P_ni(n_k_matrix_p[i,1],n_k_matrix_p[i,2],eta1,eta2,p)
}
```

To make it reproducible:

```
eta1 <- 10
eta2 <- 5
p <- 0.4
n_k_matrix <- expand.grid(c(1:20),c(1:20))
n_k_matrix <- n_k_matrix[n_k_matrix[,1] >=n_k_matrix[,2],]
n_k_matrix <- n_k_matrix[order(n_k_matrix[,1]),]
```

The n_k_matrix contains my numbers for Pn and Pi.
Unfortunately the loop is still faster than using apply.
Does anyone have any idea how to speed things up?

Comment: Not certain I understand complete. `choose` arguments `n` and `k` are *"numeric vectors"* (from the help page), and I just confirmed that `choose(4:6, 1:3)` works. Also, you mention using `for` and `apply`, but neither is included here.

Comment: I add the for-loop!

Comment: Please just edit your question; complex code and/or data in comments is really hard to grok.

Comment: Maybe I wasnt specific enough: choose, does take vectors, but I need to define I vector for every Pn-Pi-pair I use, so to be more precise choose would need to take a matrix or a couple of vectors.

Comment: Can you make your example *reproducible*? You are almost there, but I would like to copy/paste/run your code, but right now if I try I will need to define my own `n_k_matrix_p`, `eta1`, `eta2`, and `p` values, and I don't know what if they should be integers, between 0 and 1, something else, etc. It would be easy if you provide some sample values. And don't make the matrix too big! Just big enough to illustrate the problem is fine.

Comment: As a possible solution, to "choose would need to take a couple of vectors", something like `outer(X = 2:10, Y = 1:5, FUN = choose)`?

Comment: I see. The problem has nothing to do with `choose`, it's because your calls to `choose` are already including a vector for each `Pn`/`Pi` pair.

Comment: Yes exactly I already create vectors of the constants, so in conclusion I would need a vector of vectors ...

Comment: It seems like, in the loop, you will frequently run `choose` on the same values again and again. Maybe you can precompute all the `choose` results once (`outer` will be helpful as in my earlier comment), store them in a matrix, and just pull out whichever ones you need rather than recomputing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can regroup or precompute some computations.

```
P_ni2 <- function(n, eta1, eta2, p, d = 1 - p) {

  res <- matrix(0, n, n)
  diag(res) <- p^seq_len(n)

  C1 <- eta1 / eta2 * p / d
  C2 <- eta2 / (eta1 + eta2) * d
  C3 <- eta1 / (eta1 + eta2)
  C2_n <- C2^seq_len(n)
  C3_n <- C3^seq_len(n)
  precomputed <- outer(0:n, 0:n, choose)

  for (j in seq_len(n)) {
    for (i in seq_len(j - 1)) {
      seq1 <- seq(i, j - 1)
      res[i, j] <- sum(
        precomputed[j-i, seq1-i+1] * precomputed[j+1, seq1+1] * C1^seq1
      ) * C2_n[j] / C3_n[i]
    }
  }

  res
}
```

Verif:

```
> system.time({
+   n_k_matrix[[3]] <- sapply(1:nrow(n_k_matrix), function(i) {
+     P_ni(n_k_matrix[i,1], n_k_matrix[i,2], eta1, eta2, p)
+   })
+ })
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
     11.799       0.000      11.797 

> system.time({
+   test <- P_ni2(400, eta1, eta2, p)
+   n_k_matrix[[4]] <- test[as.matrix(n_k_matrix[, 2:1])]
+ })
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
      2.328       0.003       2.341


> all.equal(n_k_matrix[[3]], n_k_matrix[[4]])
[1] TRUE
```

Note that I first store the results in the upper triangle of a squared matrix. Then, I convert it in your data frame format (that you call a matrix by the way).

This solution is 5 times faster for `n = 400`. I think you could improve it by recoding the double-loop (only) in Rcpp.

Comment: Thank you very much this improved my complete code by around 10% ! Is my format not a matrix? Because if I intentionally used the matrix class because it is faster than data.frame ...

Comment: I meant that `n_k_matrix` is not a matrix but a data frame (so, poor choice of naming).